# Region of integration for $\int_0^2 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^1 \sqrt{1+x^3}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Evaluate the integral by reversing the order
$$\int_0^2 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^1 \sqrt{1+x^3}\,dx\,dy$$

What happens to the limit $\sqrt{y} \leq t \leq 1$ for $0 \leq y \leq 2$ in the region of integration. Should we split the ranges of $x$ as $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $1 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: I think that would be the correct approach, yea

Comment: Be careful!  $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\neq\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}y$ when $a>b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration region is

[image]

and then you can write your integral as follows

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{1+x^3}dy\,dx-\int_1^\sqrt{2}\int_{x^2}^2\sqrt{1+x^3}dy\,dx$$